# Is there a screenshot program in Cinnamon 5.2.7?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, cinnamon

I have installed Cinnamon 5.2.7 alongside Gnome 42.5 in Ubuntu Jammy 22.04. Now I have problem taking screenshots in Cinnamon. In Gnome everything is fine, but the screenshots program seems to work in Gnome only. Cinnamon Applet requires old program gnome-screenshots.

Comment: You can `apt install gnome-screenshot` and it should work?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Cinnamon indeed uses `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot`

gnome-screenshot should work on both though; if you don't have it install it using `sudo apt install gnome-screenshot`.
Alternative: you can install Flameshot (you did not see that one I assume?). That one is in the repositories for both Gnome and Cinnamon (me using 5.6.7 though).